# How does Collections and List store objects of different types ? Is it Possible?

Tags: c#

How does generic collections and List store objects of different types ? Is it Possible?

Because collections and List are a replacement for arraylist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main advantage of generic collections is that you can specify the exact type you want to store in the collection and don't need boxing.

You have some options here:

- You stick to the nongeneric collections in the `System.Collections` namespace which take object as a parameter.
- You create a generic collection of type object. This is more or less the same as above, but you can use all the extension methods that exist for `IEnumerable<T>`.
- You create a generic collection of a common interface, that all types you want to store, implement.

Answer (score 6):

If you need to store various types, you need to declare your collection to be of a type that all the other types are compatible with.

So for example, to put both a `MemoryStream` and a `FileStream` in a list, you might have a `List<Stream>`:

```
List<Stream> streams = new List<Stream>();
streams.Add(new MemoryStream());
streams.Add(new FileStream(...));
```

For more disparate types, you may need to go as far as `List<object>`:

```
List<object> objects = new List<object>();
objects.Add("hello"); // A String
objects.Add(5); // An Int32
objects.Add(new Button());
objects.Add(Guid.NewGuid());
```

Note that in this case, value type values will be boxed - whereas they wouldn't in a list of that specific value type.

To use any type-specific members of elements, you'd need to check that they were the right type and cast them, e.g. with `is` and a cast, or `as`:

```
string maybeString = objects[0] as string;
if (maybeString != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("String of length {0}", maybeString.Length);
}
```

Comment: I was always under the impression that checking for type via `as` is generally frowned upon?

Comment: @KyleBaran: Yes, it's generally a bad idea - just like it's *generally* a bad idea to mix types within a single collection. But sometimes it's the least bad of all the alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

well, you need to make the list store the most common denominator;  if you want to store anything, you need a `List<object>()` or perhaps `List<IMyCommonInterface>()`.

However, in my experience, if you find yourself coding like this, you might want to reconsider your architecture.

Perhaps you could explain the solution you're trying to achieve ?